# Как добавить существующий файл в проект XCode 8 Swift 3 и получить к нему доступ

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

Как добавить существующий файл в проект XCode 8 Swift 3 и получить к нему доступ через FileManager?

Answer (score 0):

Для начала добавить существующий файл в проект. Затем получить к нему доступ. Как пример txt:

```
func readTXT() -> String {
    // Для лучшего понимания по пунктам:
    // Получаем путь к файлу
    guard let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "SomeText", ofType: "txt") else {
        return ""
    }
    // Читаем содержимое файла
    guard let data = FileManager.default.contents(atPath: filePath) else {
        return ""
    }
    // Получаем строку
    guard let text = String.init(data: data, encoding: .ascii) else {
        return ""
    }
    // Возвращаем полученную строку. Если на каком-то этапе возникла проблема, возвращаем пустую строку, можно добавить ошибки, их обработку и прочее.
    return text
}
```